# creating a chart for a game- Asm

Tags: assembly

I wanted to ask about a chart I tried to make. I don't understand why it's not working, i did many tracking tables in order to find the problem, but I coulden't find any.
The chart is for a game called "submarines" or " battleships".just note that the chart must be build with the array "Submarine".

```
Data Segment
Horizontal DB ' -----------',10,36
DisplayNum db ' 1 2 3 4 5',10,36
Vertical DB ('|')
Submarine DB 25 Dup ('?')
Data ends

Code segment
Assume CS:Code,DS:Data


Table PROC
MOV SI,0
MOV BL,'1'
MOV CX,5
MOV DX, OFFSET DisplayNum
MOV AH,9H
INT 21H

Table2:MOV DX, OFFSET Horizontal
MOV AH,9H
INT 21H

MOV DL,BL
MOV AH,9
INT 21H
MOV DI,5

Anew:MOV DL,Vertical
MOV AH,9H
INT 21H

MOV DL,Submarine[SI]
MOV AH,9H
INT 21H
DEC DI
INC SI
CMP DI,0
JNZ Anew

MOV DL,Vertical
MOV AH,9H
INT 21H

MOV DL,10
MOV AH,2
INT 21H
MOV DL,13
INT 21H

INC BL
LOOP Table2


MOV DX, OFFSET Horizontal
MOV AH,9H
INT 21H
Table endp


START:
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
CALL Table

FINISH:MOV AX,4C00H
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: To make it easier for people to answer your question (and to avoid downvotes) you need to be more specific. For example, what is the problem (what is the expected behavior, and what is the actual behavior)?

Comment: the problem is that one of the loops is endless, but when i look at the program i can't find any.i just could infer that after runing the program.

Comment: tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: I see real ninjas coding in ASM still exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that `INT21/AH=9` displays DS:DX byte-by-byte until it reaches '$'=0x24=36.

In your strings `Horizontal`, `DisplayNum` the character before is a 10=0x0A=line feed. There is no CR. You need 0dH,0Ah,'$' or 13,10,36.

After showing your first horizontal line, you are then assigning the value in `BL`, presumably '1'=31H=49, to `DL` so DS:DX will point to `Horizontal`+49 - a byte near to the end of the `submarine` array. Then you are executing `INT21/AH=9` again - so you'll get the end of the `submarine` array and random garbage up to the next '$' byte displayed. If you want to display the byte in `DL` try using `INT21/AH=02`

You then reload `DL` with `Vertical` and wherever `DX` is pointing, write that out again as a string until you find '$' again. And repeat that performance, this time loading `DL` from `submarine+SI`. You do that 5 times, again set `DL` to `vertical` and output *that* string - with whatever `DH` then happens to contain.

Finally, you send CR and LF - but in the wrong order (look - you really, really don't want to know why CRLF - it's a very dry story...) and finally repeat the whole idea 5 times until `CX` is reduced to 0 by the `LOOP`, then the horizontal line again, and since there's no `RETURN` no doubt flow through to START: and repeat the whole rigmarole from the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

```
INT 21H
Table endp
```

You're missing a `RET` before the end of the procedure. So what probably happens is that it simply continues to execute the code directly following it (i.e. the code after `START`), thereby creating an endless "loop" (until you run out of stack space).